# Mediawiki won't work because of httpd start error

Tags: linux, apache-httpd, mediawiki

My mediawiki install in httpd server for more than two years，today I get the following error when i restart httpd

```
    Unable to verify certificate 'Server-Cert'. Add "NSSEnforceValidCerts off" to nss.conf so the server can start until the problem can be resolved.
```

I solve this by add NSSEnforceValidCerts off in nss.conf in the conf.d folder.But   httpd still won't start with  following error:

```
   [warn]  module nss_module is already loaded, skipping
   [warn] _default_ VirtualHost overlap on port 8443, the first has precedence (98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 8443
```

[image]

how to solve it? thanks

Comment: First It seems you have 2 virtual hosts on port 8443, you would need to add NameVirtualHost yourip:8443. Second maybe your certificate has expired ? Do you use mod_nss ? if not you can disable it maybe.

Comment: I don't know if Mediawiki use mod_nss?

Comment: Well you should check the Mediawiki doc in that case.

Comment: Good you found the solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution in my case was to comment the following lines out of the /etc/httpd/conf.d/nss.conf file:

```
#LoadModule nss_module modules/libmodnss.so
#Listen 8443
```

service httpd start 
and it works again!
thanks for all!

Answer (score 0):

`httpd` cannot bind to port 8443, which usually means either another program is already using it:

```
netstat -tulpn | grep 8443
```

should tell you which one, or your OS security layer (SELinux or AppArmor, depending on your flavour of distribution) doesn't let `httpd` bind to that port:

```
getenforce
```

will tell you if SELinux is active. At that point, you need to decide if you either want to go down the more secure, but long path of writing extra rules to allow `httpd` access to that port, or disable SELinux.

Comment: netstat -tulpn | grep 8443 return nothing and getenforce return permissive. I have update it in my question